# Free Virtual Drive Software

Tags: dvd, iso-image, compact-disc, virtual-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free Windows ISO Mounting Software](https://superuser.com/questions/3804/free-windows-iso-mounting-software)

Are there any other free virtual drive creation software? Daemon tools was good, but it has become a nagware

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [MagicDisc](http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-magicdisc-overview.htm).

There is also [Virtual Clonedrive](http://www.slysoft.com/virtual-clonedrive.html).

Also, see these links:

> https://superuser.com/questions/3804/free-windows-iso-mounting-software
>   https://superuser.com/questions/14461/virtual-cd-dvd-softwares
>   https://superuser.com/questions/36499/windows-xp-is-there-a-small-free-way-to-use-and-mount-images-iso-files-withou